# Adjusted Bounce Rate destroyed my Pageviews tracking with GTM

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, bounce, pageviews

I've implemented a new Timer trigger type (10secs) to adjust the bounce rates on 2 different websites.

The first is working perfectly but the second... The pageviews were destroyed, Google Analytics is tracking around 7-8 pageviews per each 100 sessions:

[image]

It's impossible to apply this for real situations. What could be happening?.

**IMPORTANT**, I'm using the same wordpress version, same theme, same plugins and different GTM accounts/workspaces. on both websites but the results are different.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics starts a session on the first hit, whether that's an event or a pageview. Send your pageviews as normal, and then at the 10 second timer of the session's first pageview you can send an interaction event (default) that serves as your bounce rate adjustment.

Comment: I did it but now, I'm getting a suggestion from Google Tag Assistant telling me that it's "Non-standard implementation". What it mean?